# Retrieve video data from local file system

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating a simple app to upload a recorded video to a web API. After recording the video in app I can successfully play the video within the app, but I'm struggling to access the video to upload it.

The video is at `assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=3AFCEC9B-17DE-4D75-9B87-0AD50BAB9BFF&ext=MOV`, which can be loaded using `MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)` so I know it exists there.

I've tried the following few methods with no success:

**Method 1**

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: thisNote.url!)
        println("This url = \(thisNote.url)")
let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: nil, error: &e)
```

error = `The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory`

**Method 2**

```
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String
let videoFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(Constants.Directories.appFolder)
let filePath = NSBundle.pathForResource(thisNote.fileName, ofType: "video/quicktime", inDirectory: Constants.Directories.appFolder)
```

filepath = `nil`

**Method 3**

```
var video:NSData = NSData()
ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (asset : ALAsset!) -> Void in
    if let rep : ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation(){

        var error: NSError?
        let length = Int(rep.size())
        let from = Int64(0)
        let data = NSMutableData(length: length)!
        let numRead = rep.getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(data.mutableBytes), fromOffset: from, length: length, error: &error)

        video = data

        self.uploadNote(video, note: thisNote)

    }
}){ (error : NSError!) -> Void in
     println("Asset library error: \(error)")
}
```

The result block is not reached, nor is the error printed.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method three was the closest to the final solution. I ended up enumerating through the asset library to find the right video file. Whilst I'm sure this is not the most efficient way to get the video, it works. Here is the code I used, I hope it helps someone......

```
    let url = NSURL(string: thisNote.url!)
    var video:NSData = NSData()
    AssetLibraryHelper.sharedInstance.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (foundAsset : ALAsset!) -> Void in
        var asset:ALAsset?

        if foundAsset == nil {
            // Workaround: Enumerate over the asset library to find matching URL
            AssetLibraryHelper.sharedInstance.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(
                ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream),
                usingBlock: { (group: ALAssetsGroup?, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
                    if group != nil {
                        group!.enumerateAssetsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Reverse, usingBlock: {(enumeratedAsset: ALAsset!, index: Int, stopGroup: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

                            if enumeratedAsset != nil {
                                    asset = enumeratedAsset
                                    stop.initialize(true)
                                    stopGroup.initialize(true)
                            }

                        })
                    }
                }, failureBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Error enumerating assets \(error)")
            })
        }
        else {
            asset = foundAsset
        }

        print("Asset is \(asset)")

        if let rep : ALAssetRepresentation = asset!.defaultRepresentation(){

            let image = UIImage(CGImage: rep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue())
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)

            var error: NSError?
            let length = Int(rep.size())
            let from = Int64(0)
            let data = NSMutableData(length: length)!
            let _ = rep.getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(data.mutableBytes), fromOffset: from, length: length, error: &error)

            video = data

            self.uploadNote(video, note: thisNote, imageFile: imageData!)

        }
        }){ (error : NSError!) -> Void in
            print("Asset library error: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: what is AssetLibraryHelper equal too?